# Reduce a number range to the shortest possible root

Tags: r

This is one of my first longer r scripts, if someone would have the time to have a look at the structure I'd be really grateful.  I'm applying a looped function that will call one of two functions - it seems like it could be better organised, but I've gone as far as i can with my limited knowledge).

The problem is better illustrated with an example (provided below), but the idea is to shorten a range of telephone number to their shortest possible root (shortest in terms of characters).

So a range encompassing 150000 - 159999 could be shortened to 15.
It gets more tricky once the range is not with easy ranges, for example, as 161001 - 169999 does not include 161000, we cant reduce it to 16, it must create the following lines: 161001 through 161009, 16101 through 16109, 1611 through 1619 and 162 through 169

This is better illustrated by running the code segment below:

```
# Set up-----------------------
x <- c('tidyverse', 'stringr')
lapply(x, require, character.only = TRUE)
rm(list = ls())
options(scipen = 12)

# Import----------------------
reduced_plan <- tribble(~start_range, ~end_range, ~prefix,
                        "1000", "9999", "10",
                        "1001", "9999", "12",
                        "1100", "9999", "00",
                        "1234", "9999", "10"
)

# PtAi internal loop -------------
build_list <- function(lwr_limit, upr_limit, chars_to_trim){
  # lwr_limit : lower limit with prefix
  # upr_limit : upper limit with prefix
  # starting_digits : entire starting range with prefix
  # chars_to_trim : integer number of trailing digits to consider

  tmp_list = list()
  cntr <- 1

  variable_digit_start <- str_sub(lwr_limit, -(chars_to_trim ), -(chars_to_trim ))
  pre_digits <- str_sub(lwr_limit, 1, -(chars_to_trim + 1))

  post_upper_digits <- paste(unlist(rep('9', chars_to_trim - 1)), collapse = '')
  post_lower_digits <- paste(unlist(rep('0', chars_to_trim - 1)), collapse = '')

  for(variable_digit in variable_digit_start:9){

    full_number_to_add <- paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit)

    lwr_implied_bound <- as.numeric(paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit, post_lower_digits))
    upr_implied_bound <- as.numeric(paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit, post_upper_digits))

    if(lwr_implied_bound >= as.numeric(lwr_limit) & upr_implied_bound <= as.numeric(upr_limit)){

      tmp_list[[cntr]] <- as.character(full_number_to_add)
      cntr <- cntr + 1

    }

  }

  return(do.call(rbind, tmp_list))

}
# PtAii Single Value -------------
check_single_value <- function(lwr_limit, upr_limit, chars_to_trim){

  variable_digit <- str_sub(lwr_limit, -(chars_to_trim), -(chars_to_trim)) #Slightly different here: varibale digit vs variable digit start
  pre_digits <- str_sub(lwr_limit, 1, -(chars_to_trim + 1))

  post_upper_digits <- paste(unlist(rep('9', chars_to_trim - 1)), collapse = '')
  post_lower_digits <- paste(unlist(rep('0', chars_to_trim - 1)), collapse = '')

  full_number_to_add <- paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit)

  lwr_implied_bound <- as.numeric(paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit, post_lower_digits))
  upr_implied_bound <- as.numeric(paste0(pre_digits, variable_digit, post_upper_digits))

  if(lwr_implied_bound >= as.numeric(lwr_limit) & upr_implied_bound <= as.numeric(upr_limit)){

    return(as.character(full_number_to_add))

  }

}
# (PtA2)Forward loop -------------------
forward_loop <- function(start_range, end_range, pref){

  lwr_limit = as.character(paste0(pref, start_range))
  upr_limit = as.character(paste0(pref, end_range))

  fwd_cntr <- 1
  fwd_tmp_list = list()

  reps = as.integer(nchar(lwr_limit) - nchar(pref) + 1)

  for(chars_to_trim in 1:reps){

    variable_digit_start <- str_sub(lwr_limit, -(chars_to_trim ), -(chars_to_trim ))

    # If all numbers to the right of variable_digit_start are 0, we can cancel them
    # If even one has a digit, we must cycle all
    dgts_after_variable <- str_sub(lwr_limit, -(chars_to_trim), nchar(lwr_limit)) #Is this right????? corrected?
    cancel_to_left <- nchar(gsub(pattern = '0', replacement = '', x = dgts_after_variable)) == 0

    if(cancel_to_left == TRUE & chars_to_trim == reps){

      # All digits have cancelled to 0 and it's not the prefix, 
      fwd_tmp_list[[fwd_cntr]] <- check_single_value(lwr_limit, upr_limit, chars_to_trim)
      fwd_cntr <- fwd_cntr + 1 

    } else if(cancel_to_left == TRUE & chars_to_trim != reps){

      # Do nothing, we skip 0s that can be cancelled, unless it's the prefix

    } else if(cancel_to_left == FALSE & chars_to_trim != reps){

      # If numbers don't cancel and it's not the prefix, loop
      fwd_tmp_list[[fwd_cntr]] <- build_list(lwr_limit, upr_limit, chars_to_trim)
      fwd_cntr <- fwd_cntr + 1 

    } else if(cancel_to_left == FALSE & chars_to_trim == reps){

      # if numbers don't cancel, and it's the prefix, no looping, just see if the prefix is eligable
      fwd_tmp_list[[fwd_cntr]] <- check_single_value(lwr_limit, upr_limit, chars_to_trim)
      fwd_cntr <- fwd_cntr + 1

    } else {

      print('problem')

    }

  }

  return(do.call(rbind, fwd_tmp_list))

}

new_plan <- reduced_plan %>%
  mutate(forward = mapply(FUN = forward_loop, reduced_plan$start_range, reduced_plan$end_range, reduced_plan$prefix, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  )

expanded_new_plan <- new_plan %>%
  unnest(forward)
```

I would really appreciate any help you can give.  Also, if there is an obviously way to do this please feel free to point it out.

Finally, leading 0s are a pain in dealing with telephone numbers, this is the reason I treat numbers as strings for a lot of the time